# how do I recover the Azure powershell context, right after creating a new VM, in a new powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure

I just followed the commands in the Azure create a Windows VM training.  After successfully creating the new VM the powershell timed out.  When I tried to continue the training I got this message:

Get-AzVMImagePublisher : No subscription found in the context.  Please ensure that the credentials you provided are
authorized to access an Azure subscription, then run Connect-AzAccount to login.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzVMImagePublisher -Location "WestUS"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzVMImagePublisher], ApplicationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.GetAzureVMImagePublisherCommand

and it keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating the VM, there should be a subscription in the tenant that you log in with your account. In PowerShell, you can login first like this:

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

It shows like this after you login with your Azure account:

[image]

Then you can get the subscription through the PowerShell command:

```
Get-AzSubscription
```

It would show the subscriptions you have. Like this:

[image]

And select the subscription through the PowerShell command:

```
Select-AzSubscription -Subscription subscription_Id
```

Then you can create the VM as you do before.